# Truly share a folder with multiple users on a computer

Tags: file-sharing, shared-folders

I have a folder in my home directory that I want to be truly shared between all users on the same computer.

So, I set the permission to be 777. Now, all users can access it and can create, ,edit, delete files in it.

However, I do not have write access to files created by other users.

How do I ensure that all files (existing as well as newly created/ copied) have rwx access to all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use bindfs.

bindfs allow multiple local users to read and write (create, delete, rename, modify...) all files (including newly created ones) from a shared directory and its subdirectories.

You can specify users by user name or group, it is very flexible.

The basic syntax (from the wiki page) is:

- Creating the shared directory

e.g. in the `/home` directory:

```
sudo mkdir /home/shared
```

NOTE: If the directory already exist skip this step.

Allow only root to access it, **we will set the permissions later with bindfs**:

```
sudo chown root: /home/shared
sudo chmod 0700 /home/shared
```

- Setting the permissions with bindfs

Now use the bindfs command to mount the shared directory with altered permissions. Syntax of the command:

```
bindfs [options] dir mountpoint
```

Example:

```
sudo bindfs -o perms=0700,mirror-only=user1:user2:user3 /home/shared /home/shared
```

- Options explained:

`perms=0700` sets the permissions to 0700 (read/write for the owner, none for the group and other)

`mirror-only=user1:user2:user3` user1, user2 and user3 will see itself as the owner of the files (user names are separated by a colon).

To automatically mount at boot, use fstab . Open fstab for editing with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add a line

- fstab example:

`bindfs#/home/shared  /home/shared  fuse  perms=0700,mirror-only=user1:user2:user3  0  0`

See - [Ubuntu wiki bindfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bindfs-SharedDirectoryLocalUsers) for group options and additional details.

Comment: bindfs seems to be very complicated. Wish there were an easy solution like this folder and everything below it will be read-write accessible to all irrespective of who created it

For some strange reason, I tried mentioning @ bodhi.zazen name in my reply but it is not showing anything :(

Answer (score 1):

The other users have to set the permissions to **rwx** for you.

If you don't want to install a new software the others users should do this (one of many options):

1. Set the *Access to Folder* permission for other users to *create & delete files*.
   Do the same with *Access to Files* permission:

[image: View]

2. And then push on *Apply Permissions to the Files*:

[image]

Comment: The other users and I need to keep setting the permissions again and again. That is painful. I wish there were an easier way of doing it.

Is Public folder the way out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use af FUSE mount (mhddfs for instance) and mount as "rw", "exec" without the "default_permissions" option. Any user should be able to read, write and execute files.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mount.fuse.8.html