# Inheriting parent folder's permissions

Tags: permissions, directory

Okay. I've installed Ubuntu on an old laptop, which I plan to stick in a drawer and never open again, for use as a file and media server, and all is going well except that I'm having some problems with permissions.

I set the Downloads folder so that it's shared through Samba and everyone and their sister has read/write permissions, which is how I want it. However, when a new folder is created inside of it, it does not inherit those permissions. Which is not how I want it.

Some googling has led to what appear to be solutions, except that they're all written for someone who actually knows what they are doing, which is not me. I've got the basics of Ubuntu down, but just barely.

Any chance someone can walk me, step by step, to a permanent solution for this? You'd have my eternal thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Bindfs is a solution that should work. I will try to give link to my question. But if that fails, click on my username and browse my questions.

[Bindfs answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158694/truly-share-a-folder-with-multiple-users-on-a-computer)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying the somewhat cryptic 'setfacl' (set file access control list) command.

```
setfacl -Rm d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rwx FolderName
```

The -m option means modify the ACL of your folder. The -R option means do it recursively.

The other symbols stand for the following:
d = default

(who to apply the permissions to)
u = user
g = group
o = other

(permissions)
r = read
w = write
x = execute

So in the example above, I've set the default (d) permissions for user (u), group (g) and other (o) to read (r) write (w) and execute (x).

I hope this is of some use.